# SemanticMediawiki: inserting category in subobjects

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-mediawiki

I've tried to add some `categories` to a `subobject` (implemented inside a template).

```
{{#subobject:
|url = https://www.instagram.com/p/CXeE2j-NT6s/
|title = Bullismo: proposta una legge in Francia per punirlo penalmente. Si rischia anche il carcere
|@tags=bullismo|violenza|leggi|punizioni|+sep=|
}}
```

Is it possible to list all the tags of all the subobjects in [this page](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Tutti_gli_articoli_di_Marco_Crepaldi).

I'm very new to SMW, I can't even figure out if the subobjects [shown properly](https://www.tematichedigenere.com/wiki/Speciale:Esplora/:Tutti-5Fgli-5Farticoli-5Fdi-5FMarco-5FCrepaldi)

Comment: It works fine, you have to click the eye symbol in the "show property" page to see each individual subobject value.

Comment: @IRA1777 thanks, is there something like IRC for semantikwiki? Or other channel more interactive to ask questions?